# Why can a trigonal genus 5 curve be represented as a plane quintic with a node?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective curve of genus 5 which a) is not hyperelliptic and b) possesses a $g_3^1$. I want to show that $X$ can be represented as a plane quintic with a node, i.e. there's a birational map $f:X\to \Bbb P^2$ which has image a plane quintic with a node. I think I can show most of this, but the main sticking point for me is why the singular point can be chosen to be a node and not a cusp.

Here's what I have so far: suppose $D$ is an effective divisor in the $g_3^1$. Then $l(D)=2$ (either because one assumes $g_3^1$ to be complete or by Clifford's theorem), and by Riemann-Roch $l(K-D)=3$. Now let $P\in X$ be arbitrary and consider $D+P$: $l(D+P)\geq l(D)=2$, and by Clifford's theorem, $l(D+P)\leq 2$, so $l(D+P)=2$. Therefore by Riemann-Roch, $l(K-D-P)=2$ and so $K-D$ is base-point free. Thus $K-D$ gives a map $f:X\to\Bbb P^2$, and $f(X)$ has degree 5 in $\Bbb P^2$. By the degree-genus formula, a plane quintic has arithmetic genus 6, so $f(X)$ must have one singular point with $\delta=1$ (where $\delta$ is the dimension of the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_{f(X),x}$ modulo $\mathcal{O}_{f(X),x}$). But I know that both nodes and cusps have $\delta=1$, so how come I can get a node and not a cusp? I suspect I'm supposed to be able to deduce this from some geometry of the canonical embedding, but I don't see it yet.

I'm also potentially a little shaky on why $f$ should be birational on to its image: I'd love to use the criteria that $l(K-D-P-Q)=l(K-D)-2$ for almost all $P,Q$ (really, all $P,Q$ except the two points over the singularity) but I'm honestly unsure how to make this argument successfully. Again, it seems I'm missing an understanding of the geometry of the canonical embedding of $X$ in $\Bbb P^4$.

Comment: A smooth curve in $\mathbb P^3$ acquires a node upon projection to $\mathbb P^2$ when one of the lines of projection is secant to the curve. A cusp arises when that secant line is taken to the limit and becomes a tangent, i.e. in some sense it is "harder" to obtain a cusp. So I think this will follow from the fact that tangents to $C \subset \mathbb P^3$ sweep out just a one-dimensional subvariety of the Grassmannian of lines in $\mathbb P^3$. I don't think there's anything you need to say about the fact that $C$ arises as the general projection of a canonical curve, but I also just woke up...

Comment: @TabesBridges that sounds like some good information to know, thanks! But I'm a little unclear about how to actually use this in my problem - I'm afraid I don't quite see how to  find a projection that will give me the plane curve (the degree doesn't seem to behave correctly). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Projecting a curve from a point on said curve decreases the degree by $1$, but projecting from a point off the curve preserves the degree. So the upshot is that you want to project the curve from a disjoint line in $\mathbb P^4$ (the same thing as projecting from two points in succession, neither on the curve).

Comment: @TabesBridges But the canonical curve in $\Bbb P^4$ is of degree $2g-2=8$, so no matter how I project that to $\Bbb P^2$ the degree is at most $8-2=6$, so it can't be a plane *quintic*. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Ugh sorry, I'm out of practice and got my invariants mixed up. You're absolutely right; this cannot be a projection of the canonical embedding.

Comment: @TabesBridges Looks like I might have jumped the gun on that! Tell me if this looks right to you: $l(K-D)=3$ means that the three points in $D$ form a line in the canonical embedding in $\Bbb P^4$, and projection from this line has degree 5 and lands in a $\Bbb P^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a general plane quintic curve with one cusp, its normalization has genus 5, and the projection from the cusp provides it with a $g_3^1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sasha. Perhaps I'm not understanding it completely, though - if $C$ is a cuspidal plane quintic and $\widetilde{C}$ is its normalization, does your answer mean that there is no map $\widetilde{C}\to\Bbb P^2$ which has image a nodal plane quintic?

Comment: Yes, because a curve of genus 5 cannot have two different $g_3^1$ (otherwise it would have a morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ onto a curve of bidegree $(3,3)$, but this is impossible because such a curve has genus 4).

Comment: Oh! I get it, and the impossibility of the map follows from Riemann-Hurwitz. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: @Sasha: Could you sketch roughly how you conclude that the normalization of general plane quintic curve with one cusp has genus $5$. My first guess was Hurwitz formula but as far as I know it's only available for nonsingular curves...

Comment: Blow up the cusp point on the plane, then the strict transform $C'$ of the curve has class $5\ell - 2e$ (because the multiplicity of the point is 2), the canonical class of the blown up plane is $-3\ell + e$, hence the canonical class of the curve is $2\ell - e$, and its degree is $(5\ell - 2e)(2\ell - e) = 5\cdot 2 - 2\cdot 1 = 8$.

Comment: alright I see, so firstly you relate the canonical classes of the blown up plane with that one of the strict transform (here = normalization of the cusp curve) via adjunction formula and then use that for non singular curves the degree of canonical divisor is $2 \times $ (genus) $ -2$, right? Thanks!

Comment: @katalaveino: Precisely.